# SQL Server 2014 Express Set Up

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014-express

I have downloaded Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 Express. I have set it up and I now need to connect to the server. I think my server name has something to do with my computer name but its not working. How do I get in?

Comment: This seems like it might be more appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), or else you need some more details about why this is programming related.

Comment: I consider this manual extremly useful https://dyball.wordpress.com/2014/04/05/error-installing-sql-express-2012-or-error-installing-sql-express-2014/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you installed SQL Server, and not just SSMS please read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531(v=sql.120).aspx

In all likelihood it was setup with the default instance name of \SQLExpress.  So to connect, you would enter machinename\SQLExpress.

Ex: `Office-PC1\SQLExpress`

> If you specify MSSQLServer for the instance name, a default instance
>   will be created. For SQL Server Express, if you specify SQLExpress for
>   the instance name, a default instance will be created.

NB: If you open the "Server Name" drop down in the SSMS "Connect To Server" window, there is a "Browse for more..." option which should help you find your installed server.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work, there is also nothing in the browse for more window

Comment: Did you actually install SQL Server?

Comment: yes I did, do I need to do something in the configuration manager?

Comment: Can I suggest going to the command line and type `net start` and see if "SQL Server" comes up?  Maybe the service isnt started.

Comment: Was just about to say open services.msc and make sure MSSQLSERVER is started :)

Comment: Great minds.  As a DBA, i start with the simplest solutions first, I've been guilty of not actually starting the service before.

Comment: What is the name of the executable you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually installed the db server, and NOT just the management tools, you can always use "localhost" (without the quotes). Have you made sure you are using port 1433? I am not sure if that was a question during the setup.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost/SQLExpress` in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)